# hyperxmp + xelatex bug: duplication of pdfkeywords

Tags: xetex, hyperref, metadata, xmp, hyperxmp

I found an annoying bug(?) relating to the `pdfkeywords` metadata field which `hyperref` allows to set. When `hyperref` is used in combination with `hyperxmp` and the document is compiled with `xelatex` the keywords are duplicated in the pdf metadata (both in the regular pdf properties and the XMP metadata).

Here's an MWO:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[xetex]{hyperref}% remove "xetex" parameter when compiling with pdflatex instead of xelatex
\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor = {Matthias},
    pdftitle = {MWO},
    pdfkeywords = {Test, MWO, This is a test, Lipsum}
}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

When I compile this with `pdflatex` (remove the `xetex` parameter in `\usepackage{hyperref}`) I get:

- in the keywords field of the PDF properties:

  ```
  Test, MWO, This is a test, Lipsum
  ```
- in the keywords field of the XMP metadata:

  ```
  Test; MWO; This is a test; Lipsum
  ```

This is the intended behaviour (`hyperxmp` replaces commas with `;` in the XMP field, cf. `hyperxmp` documentation).

However, when compiling the MWO with `xelatex` I get:

- in the keywords field of the PDF properties:

  ```
  "Test, MWO, This is a test, Lipsum"; Test;  MWO;  This is a test;  Lipsum
  ```
- in the keywords field of the XMP metadata:

  ```
  "Test, MWO, This is a test, Lipsum"; Test; MWO; This is a test; Lipsum
  ```

As you can see the keywords are repeated. First the `,`-separated is put between `""` (and treated as a single keyword) and then the `;`-separated sequence follows.

I have tried changing the package loading order and compiling with `xelatex` without specifying the `xetex` parameter on `\usepackage{hyperref}`, all to no avail.
Any ideas on how to fix or work around this?

Comment: In my experience, the authors of both these packages are not active on this site, but are regularly found on `comp.text.tex`, and `de.comp.text.tex` in the case of the `hyperref` package.

Comment: I wrote the author hyperxmp an email linking to this question. Fingers crossed for his response.
I'll also post in the `comp.text.tex` group. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Post on `comp.text.tex`: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.text.tex/W6gmK5WE8jA/discussion

Comment: A remark for the semicolons. They are not set by hyperxmp or hyperref. Probably are they used as separators by the application that displays the XMP data. BTW, which application do you use for showing the XMP data (not the PDF information entries)?

Answer (score 6):

Package `hyperxmp` in version 2011/06/12 v1.4 does not use UTF-8 for the XMP data.
Instead the data bytes are given in PDFDocEncoding or even UTF-16BE. Also its
trimspaces macro breaks because of this. The BOM (byte order mark) is not written
correctly in case XeTeX, ...

Strings as result of `\pdfstringdef` (`\@pdfauthor` and friends) can have
different encodings dependent of option settings and drivers. `\ifHy@unicode` is
not useful for the encoding detection. With `pdfencoding=auto` the string can
also have PDFDocEncoding! Also there is an exception for XeTeX, where the
string might have big chars (with character code > 127). XeTeX unlike all other
drivers only provide a very ugly unspecified and incomplete interface if an
application wants to write arbitrary binary data.

The string detection can be done by looking for the BOM that `\pdfstringdef` sets
for Unicode strings. Additionally (for XeTeX) the string needs to be checked
for big chars.

In the next step the XMP data are written. Package `hyperxmp` uses UTF-8.
Therefore the patch below encodes the string in UTF-8 with XML escapings.
(Using the original PDFDocEncoding or Unicode are wrong, both encodings
differ to UTF-8.)

The patch also fixes the BOM marker for XeTeX and LuaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  pdfencoding=auto
%  unicode,
]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor = {Matthias<abc>},
    pdftitle = {MWO\textalpha\textomega},
    pdfkeywords = {Test, MWO, This is a test, Lipsum}
}

\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}[2010/04/26]
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\usepackage{ifluatex}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifhyxmp@unicodetex
\ifluatex
  \hyxmp@unicodetextrue
\else\ifxetex
  \hyxmp@unicodetextrue
\fi\fi

\renewcommand*{\hyxmp@xmlify}[1]{%
  \gdef\hyxmp@xmlified{}%
  % Escaped PDF string -> PDFDocEncoding/Unicode
  \EdefUnescapeString\hyxmp@text{#1}%
  \ifhyxmp@unicodetex
    % PDFDocEncoding/Unicode -> UTF-32BE
    \hyxmp@is@unicode\hyxmp@text{%
      \StringEncodingConvert
      \hyxmp@text\hyxmp@text{utf16be}{utf32be}%
    }{%
      \ifxetex
        \hyxmp@xetex@crap
      \else
        \StringEncodingConvert
        \hyxmp@text\hyxmp@text{pdfdoc}{utf32be}%
      \fi
    }%
    % UTF-32BE -> UTF-32BE as hex string
    \EdefEscapeHex\hyxmp@text{\hyxmp@text}%
    % UTF-32BE -> XML in ASCII
    \edef\hyxmp@text{%
      \expandafter
    }\expandafter\hyxmp@toxml@unicodetex\hyxmp@text
    \relax\relax\relax\relax\relax\relax\relax\relax
  \else
    % PDFDocEncoding/Unicode -> UTF-8
    \hyxmp@is@unicode\hyxmp@text{%
      \StringEncodingConvert
      \hyxmp@text\hyxmp@text{utf16be}{utf8}%
    }{%
      \StringEncodingConvert
      \hyxmp@text\hyxmp@text{pdfdoc}{utf8}%
    }%
    % UTF-8 -> UTF-8 as hex string
    \EdefEscapeHex\hyxmp@text{\hyxmp@text}%
    % UTF-8 as hex string -> XML in UTF-8 as hex string
    \edef\hyxmp@text{%
      \expandafter\hyxmp@toxml\hyxmp@text\@empty\@empty
    }%
    % XML in UTF-8 as hexstring -> XML in UTF-8
    \EdefUnescapeHex\hyxmp@text{\hyxmp@text}%
  \fi
  \global\let\hyxmp@xmlified\hyxmp@text
}
\begingroup
  \lccode`\<=254 %
  \lccode`\>=255 %
  \catcode254=12 %
  \catcode255=12 %
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \def\hyxmp@is@unicode#1{%
    \expandafter\hyxmp@@is@unicode#1<>\@nil
  }%
  \def\hyxmp@@is@unicode#1<>#2\@nil{%
    \ifx\\#1\\%
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
  }%
}
\def\hyxmp@toxml@unicodetex#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
  \ifx#1\relax
  \else
    \ifnum"#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8>127 %
      \uccode`\*="#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8\relax
      \uppercase{%
        \edef\hyxmp@text{\hyxmp@text *}%
      }%
    \else\ifnum"#7#8=`\< %
      \edef\hyxmp@text{\hyxmp@text &lt;}%
    \else\ifnum"#7#8=`\& %
      \edef\hyxmp@text{\hyxmp@text &amp;}%
    \else\ifnum"#7#8=`\> %
      \edef\hyxmp@text{\hyxmp@text &gt;}%
    \else\ifnum"#7#8=`\ %
      \edef\hyxmp@text{\hyxmp@text\space}%
    \else
      \uccode`\*="#7#8\relax
      \uppercase{%
        \edef\hyxmp@text{\hyxmp@text *}%
      }%
    \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
    \expandafter\hyxmp@toxml@unicodetex
  \fi
}
\def\hyxmp@skipzeros#1{%
  \ifx#10%
    \expandafter\hyxmp@skipzeros
  \fi
}
\def\hyxmp@toxml#1#2{%
  \ifx#1\@empty
  \else
    \ifnum"#1#2=`\& %
      26616D703B% &amp;
    \else\ifnum"#1#2=`\< %
      266C743B% &lt;
    \else\ifnum"#1#2=`\> %
      2667743B%
    \else
      #1#2%
    \fi\fi\fi
    \expandafter\hyxmp@toxml
  \fi
}

% In case of xetex the strings by \pdfstringdef can contain
% big chars, then the string ist treated as Unicode.
\begingroup
\def\x#1{\endgroup
  \def\hyxmp@xetex@crap{%
    \edef\hyxmp@try{%
      \expandafter\hyxmp@SpaceOther\hyxmp@text#1\@nil
    }%
    \let\hyxmp@crap@result=N%
    \expandafter\hyxmp@crap@test\hyxmp@try\relax
    \ifx\hyxmp@crap@result Y%
      \let\hyxmp@text\@empty
      \expandafter\hyxmp@crap@convert\hyxmp@try\relax
    \else
      \StringEncodingConvert
      \hyxmp@text\hyxmp@text{pdfdoc}{utf32be}%
    \fi
  }%
}\x{ }
\begingroup
  \catcode`\~=12 %
  \lccode`\~=`\ %
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \def\hyxmp@SpaceOther#1 #2\@nil{%
    #1%
    \ifx\relax#2\relax
      \expandafter\@gobble
    \else
      ~%
      \expandafter\@firstofone
    \fi
    {\hyxmp@SpaceOther#2\@nil}%
  }%
}
\def\hyxmp@crap@test#1{%
  \ifx#1\relax
  \else
    \ifnum`#1>127 %
      \let\hyxmp@crap@result=Y%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\hyxmp@skiptorelax
    \else
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\hyxmp@crap@test
    \fi
  \fi
}
\def\hyxmp@skiptorelax#1\relax{}
\def\hyxmp@crap@convert#1{%
  \ifx#1\relax
  \else
    \edef\hyxmp@num{\number`#1}%
    \ifnum\hyxmp@num>"FFFFFF %
      \lccode`\!=\intcalcDiv{\hyxmp@num}{\number"1000000}\relax
      \lowercase{\edef\hyxmp@text{\hyxmp@text!}}%
      \edef\hyxmp@num{\intcalcMod{\hyxmp@num}{\number"1000000}}%
    \else
      \edef\hyxmp@text{\hyxmp@text\hyxmp@zero}%
    \fi
    \ifnum\hyxmp@num>"FFFF %
      \lccode`\!=\intcalcDiv{\hyxmp@num}{\number"10000}\relax
      \lowercase{\edef\hyxmp@text{\hyxmp@text!}}%
      \edef\hyxmp@num{\intcalcMod{\hyxmp@num}{\number"10000}}%
    \else
      \edef\hyxmp@text{\hyxmp@text\hyxmp@zero}%
    \fi
    \ifnum\hyxmp@num>"FF %
      \lccode`\!=\intcalcDiv{\hyxmp@num}{\number"100}\relax
      \lowercase{\edef\hyxmp@text{\hyxmp@text!}}%
      \edef\hyxmp@num{\intcalcMod{\hyxmp@num}{\number"100}}%
    \else
      \edef\hyxmp@text{\hyxmp@text\hyxmp@zero}%
    \fi
    \ifnum\hyxmp@num>0 %
      \lccode`\!=\hyxmp@num\relax
      \lowercase{\edef\hyxmp@text{\hyxmp@text!}}%
    \else
      \edef\hyxmp@text{\hyxmp@text\hyxmp@zero}%
    \fi
    \expandafter\hyxmp@crap@convert
  \fi
}
\begingroup
  \catcode0=12 %
  \gdef\hyxmp@zero{^^00}%
\endgroup

\def\hyxmp@text{aö€x}
\tracingmacros=1
\hyxmp@xetex@crap
\tracingmacros=0

\renewcommand*{\hyxmp@list@to@xml}[3]{%
  \ifx#3\@empty
  \else
    \hyxmp@add@to@xml{%
_________<dc:#1>^^J%
____________<rdf:#2>^^J%
    }%
    \bgroup
      \hyxmp@xmlify{#3}%
      \hyxmp@commas@to@list\hyxmp@list{\hyxmp@xmlified}%
      \def\@elt##1{%
        \hyxmp@add@to@xml{%
_______________<rdf:li>##1</rdf:li>^^J%
        }%
      }%
      \hyxmp@list
    \egroup
    \hyxmp@add@to@xml{%
____________</rdf:#2>^^J%
_________</dc:#1>^^J%
    }%
  \fi
}

\begingroup
  \ifhyxmp@unicodetex
    \lccode`\!="FEFF %
    \lowercase{%
      \gdef\hyxmp@bom{!}
    }%
  \else
    \catcode`\^^ef=12
    \catcode`\^^bb=12
    \catcode`\^^bf=12
    \gdef\hyxmp@bom{^^ef^^bb^^bf}%
  \fi
\endgroup

\def\hyxmp@construct@packet{%
  \gdef\hyxmp@xml{}%
  \hyxmp@add@to@xml{<?xpacket begin="\hyxmp@bom" %
id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>^^J%
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="3.1-702">^^J%
___<rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns\hyxmp@hash">^^J%
  }%
  \hyxmp@pdf@schema
  \hyxmp@xmpRights@schema
  \hyxmp@dc@schema
  \hyxmp@photoshop@schema
  \hyxmp@mm@schema
  \hyxmp@add@to@xml{%
___</rdf:RDF>^^J%
</x:xmpmeta>^^J%
\hyxmp@padding
<?xpacket end="w"?>^^J%
  }%
}

\renewcommand*{\hyxmp@reencode}[1]{%
  % dummy only used for \@pdfmetalang in \begin{document}
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
    \ifx\@pdflang\@empty
      \let\@pdfmetalang=\hyxmp@x@default
    \else
      \edef\@pdfmetalang{\@pdflang}%
    \fi
    \hyxmp@xmlify\@pdfmetalang
  }{}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

I have not tested all possible cases and drivers, thus there might be
some unrevealed problems. But maybe the patch helps in improving the
package.

Comment: I haven't yet found the time to test this, but thanks for your input. Perhaps this patch should also be submitted to the author of hyperxmp?

Comment: @Matthias Check version 2.0 of [hyperxmp](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperxmp/hyperxmp.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

This is solved as of 2020. You also do not need to specify the driver of hyperref manually any more.